# Wireless connection keeps dropping

Tags: linux, wifi, wlan, asus

A little while ago I installed Ubuntu on my tower because I was getting tired of Windows; but it seems that either my internet router hates Linux, or the driver keeps choking on itself, because at random intervals, the internet connection will just drop out of nowhere.

Sometimes it's within minutes of turning the computer on, sometimes it's within hours, but it's always the same.

Unity will tell me that it is connected, but nothing is able to make a connection, pages fail to load, DropBox struggles etc.

Sometimes I'm able to reconnect just by disconnecting from wireless for 30 seconds or so, then reconnecting. Sometimes I'm forced to reboot the computer.

So how would I go by making the connection stable?

A bit hardware information:

- 64-bit Intel Sandy Bridge i7-3770 @ 3.4 GHz
- ASUS PCE-N15 Wireless N Adapter

Comment: Just a hint. At work we experienced the same kind of issues: some Dell laptops being slow or experiencing connection drops although the majority of connected devices (computers included) did work perfectly. After flashing the wifi controller (driving the Aruba access points) and eventually updating the wireless driver in Windows the problem disappeared. So don't be too quick to exclude an issue on your wifi router.

Comment: @Nasha so what do you propose? messing with the router is out of the question since it isn't mine, it's the ISP's..

Comment: Have you tried forcing your wireless network in 54g only? If you may not touch the router's firmware, I guess you'll have little to no possibility. The only thing I see is make sure you have the latest drivers and the proper kernel. Other than that maybe you could act upon advanced wireless parameters (such as frame burst, transmission rate, beacon interval, fragmentation threshold, aso) on your computer but that is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I tried to install the drivers, but they wouldn't compile..

Comment: What are those drivers? I personally am not fond of compiling on binary distributions (I come from Gentoo where compiling is a habit) so I'd rather use the distro's repository instead. Shall I suppose you previously had the latest (stable or testing) drivers from Ubuntu/Debian repository? Just in case, you might try the drivers from the "unstable" repository.

Comment: They don't appear in the driver selection thingy, and I'm not familiar enough with what's in the package manager to search for anything in there, I tried to download the drivers from Asus's website, and compile them, but apparently from what I gather, the driver uses an outdated library, so some of the struct fields in the driver no longer exist...

Comment: Yes, that's why it's preferable to use the package manager for the maintainers have already taken care of such issues. Not talking about regenerating the init ramdisk, too. See if [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) helps. You'll also have to use [apt pinning](http://www.binarytides.com/enable-testing-repo-debian/) to prevent stable packages to be upgraded with those in the testing/unstable branch.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you are probably in need of proprietary drivers, which might be why you can't find them. There should be a way to enable `non-free` packages. Check the "Package manager" software in Ubuntu for it spares you all the dirty work of adding repositories.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be an option